# Rooting log files with daemon mode

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, apache2.4

I'm using mod_wsgi (v.4.5.20), installed with pip, in daemon mode, using a "main" apache instance as front (reverse proxy). I'm serving a django application, the "main" server hosts some other applications.

I'ld like to record the log files to a "known" directory. For now, the log files are recorded into the directory generated by the daemon-mode, aka. `--server-root` directory. The process is launched through a systemd service.

On the "main" apache settings, I've set the `ErrorLog` and `CustomLog` directives to my "wanted" log directory, but no files are recorded.

The "main" apache settings: (Note the X-Forwarded-For switch for company reverse proxy)

https://gist.github.com/frague59/0c9717bd5668140de392019874373f0a

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

When you use `mod_wsgi-express` behind a front end Apache serving as proxy, the `mod_wsgi-express` configuration is completely independent to the front end. If you want to change where logs go for `mod_wsgi-express` use the `--log-directory` option. Presuming `mod_wsgi-express` is started as not root user, it will not be able to write to a `root` owned directory. If it needed to, you would need to start it as `root` and define `--user` and `--group` options to then be what user and group you want the WSGI application to run as. Because it start as `root` initially, then it can write logs to a `root` owned directory. Run `mod_wsgi-express` with the `--help` option to see all the command line options.

Comment: thanks Graham, I had not seen the --log-directory option.